# insert into with combination of inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

How can I make an insert statement of this select statement?

```
SELECT et 
 FROM user 
      inner join  petrazafa.class_room 
      using(id) 
where title like '%11%' 
   or  title like '%12%';
```

I need to insert into all `et` = 1;

thanks

Comment: doesn't work
INSERT INTO `user`(et)
SELECT class_id 
FROM user 
      inner join  petrazafa.class_room 
      using(id) 
 where title like '%11%' 
      or  title like '%12%'
values (1) ;

Answer (score 3):

*Edit 1 :*

I think there's an answer here : [Use select query inside the Insert query for the same table name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html?ff=nopfpls)

For you :

```
INSERT INTO `yourtable`(et)
SELECT et 
FROM user 
      inner join  petrazafa.class_room 
      using(id) 
 where title like '%11%' 
      or  title like '%12%';
```

Watch doc :

[INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html?ff=nopfpls)

Doc Exemple :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
  INSERT INTO user( 1 as et )
SELECT et
    FROM user 
      inner join  petrazafa.class_room 
      using(id) 
where title like '%11%' 
   or  title like '%12%';
```

Comment: no just a quick example but just realised i missed the select off the query :/

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to update `et=1` for `title like '%11%' or  title like '%12%'`

for that

```
update user u inner join petrazafa.class_room  c on u.id=c.id set et=1  where title like '%11%' 
or title like '%12%'
```

Comment: update user u 
 inner join class_room c on u.class_id=c.id 
 set et=1  
where title like '%11%'  or title like '%12%'