# InnoDb how to create a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table **articles** and I want to create another table **summaries** that is a child of articles table.

I've used the following sql to create summaries table but however mysql keeps throwing an error **#1072 - Key column 'article_id' doesn't exist in table**

```
CREATE TABLE summaries(
summary_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
summary TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ( summary_id),
FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES articles(article_id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have `article_id` in your table `summaries`, you may mean this:

```
   FOREIGN KEY (summary_id) REFERENCES articles(article_id)
```

if you want make `summary_id` as foreign key to article_id in articles table.

But make sure they have same structure properties.

EDIT:

or create a column article_id in summaries table and make it foreign key

```
  CREATE TABLE summaries(
  summary_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  summary TEXT,
  article_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY ( summary_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES articles(article_id)
  )ENGINE=INNODB;
```

EDIt:

```
 INSERT INTO `summaries` (summary,article_id)
 VALUES ($yoursummryVar , (SELECT article_id 
 FROM articles
  WHERE ........)
 )
```

i didnt test it.

Comment: But I do have an article_id in the articles table and I want the summaries table to belong to the articles table

Comment: yes this you have , but you dont have article_id in summaries table

Comment: So I figure I should just create an article_id and repeat that

Comment: yes , create a column article_id in summaries table

Comment: @Mutuma check my edit. make sure aritcle_id this you will created have same structure as article_id in articles table

Comment: if you dont know , then show your create table articles

Comment: Thanks I have done it. But how do I like insert a summary from an article?

Comment: you insert it by inner join . join the two tables , like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362752/insert-into-with-combination-of-inner-join

Comment: Hey. I read the article and checked out some inner_joins videos but its like inner joins is used to select data from related tables. Not inserting data

Comment: Please write an example of how you would insert a summary since what I'm getting mostly is for selecting

Comment: if wanna a real answer, just post new question with sample data from both tables and how you wish .and link me to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559796/how-to-insert-data-into-a-child-table-in-mysql/22559910?noredirect=1#22559910