# How to insert data into a child table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, relational-database, inner-join

I have 2 tables, an articles and a summaries table.

The summaries table is a child of the articles table and I would like to add data into the summaries table through the articles table.

The sql for the summaries table is as follows:

```
  CREATE TABLE summaries(
   summary_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   article_id INT,
   summary TEXT,
   PRIMARY KEY(summary_id),
   FOREIGN KEY(article_id) REFERENCES articles(article_id)
  )ENGINE=INNODB;
```

How do I add a summary into the summaries table and have the article_id equal to the article_id in my articles table?

Here is how I'm saving my data to articles table:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO articles  (url, domain, favicon, title) VALUES ( '$url','$domain','$favicon','$title')";
    if (mysql_query($sql)){
        $s = "SELECT max(article_id) from articles"; 
        $object1 = mysql_query($s);
    }
```

here is what I'm trying to do:

```
       $large_summary = $article_array['summary'];
       foreach ($large_summary as $summary){
          // $summary_sql = "INSERT INTO summaries SET `summary`=(SELECT `sum`.`summary` FROM summaries as sum, articles as art WHERE art.article_id=sum.article_id AND art.article_id=$object1 -> article_id)";
        $summary_sql = "INSERT INTO `summaries` (summary,article_id) VALUES ('$summary' , ('SELECT article_id FROM articles WHERE article.article_id=summary.article_id AND article.article_id = $object1 -> article_id' ))";
        echo $summary_sql;
        $summary_sql_query = mysql_query($summary_sql);

    if(!mysql_query($sql2)){
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
        echo "$summary <br>";
    }
```

I'm looping through the large_summary array to obtain an individual summary which I want to save to the database via the article it is for

Comment: Did you try an `INSERT INTO summaries ...`?

Comment: If I do that. I already had created a parent table and filled it up with data and since my keys are on auto_increment the article won't be associated with the summary

Comment: sample data will be much clear what you want.

Comment: @echo_Me Running your code returns an error, ** Query was empty**

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO summaries SET `summary`=
(SELECT `art`.`summary` FROM summaries as sum, articles as art WHERE
art.article_id=sum.article_id AND art.article_id=123)

Here '123' is a sample article_id i am passing. You have to pass your real article_id
```

Comment: could you please walk me through the code. I'm from a ruby on rails background and ActiveRecord abstracts me from the sql so this is a bit new to me

Comment: You could start from the 2nd line since the first is easy

Comment: Second line is the sub query. Here i am selecting the 'summary' from the articles table by joining the two tables using the 'article_id' and passed a article_id value Ex. '123'. In this query the summary of the article_id '123' will be inserted to the summaries table

Comment: I have understood the code now. I'm wondering something though. The data i'm inputting is really dynamic and the summary table is empty and the articles table is on row 17 so no article_id will be equal to sum.article_id. I'm using php. How would you write an sql for this if you where getting data after e.g. every minute?

Comment: And btw I run the sql and got an error: ** #1054 - Unknown column 'art.summary' in 'field list'**

Comment: Instead of passing 'art.summary', please pass the `art`.`YOUR SUMMARY COLUMN NAME FROM ARTICLE TABLE`

Comment: I do not have a summary column in the article table, but I tweaked that part to 'sum.summary' and the tested it on tthe sql tab  of phpmyadmin and it run. However I was in a dilemma where to put the summary content. For example how would you input the summary: "my name is Mutuma" into summaries via article_id: 5

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
INSERT INTO `summaries` (summary,article_id)
    VALUES ($yoursummryVar , (SELECT article_id 
                              FROM articles
                              WHERE ........)
    )
```